# Find and delete up a nested chain

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I have created a Greasemonkey script with the purpose of hiding tiles in a tabular view. Specifically, these 'tiles' (articles) are a wrapped around a  which is identified by having a specific icon inside: `::before`

While I am able to extract these and interact with them, I am unable to navigate up the chain and hide these from the user such that:

```
<article class="..." itemprop="listItemElement">
<a ...>
<div ...>
<div ...>
<span>
::before
</span>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</article>
```

Any time I identify the `::before`, I would like to 'navigate' upwards and hide the article with itemprop="listItemElement" from view.

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Elements have a [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) and a [`.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) property. Use either to walk up the tree, testing for that attribute and value as you go.

Comment: `element.closest('article')`?